# What is the best bound for $f'$ knowing bounds on $f$ and $f'''$?

Tags: analysis, derivatives, taylor-expansion, interpolation-theory

Let $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ be a three-times differentiable function. Suppose $|f(x)|\le 1$ and $|f'''(x)|\le 3$ for any $x\in \mathbb R$. Show that $|f'(x)|\le 1$ for any $x\in \mathbb R$.

The hint to this question is to apply Taylor's theorem on $[x-h,x]$ and $[x,x+h]$ for any $x\in \mathbb R$ and $h>0$. I have
$$
\begin{align}
f(x-h)&=f(x)-f'(x)h+{f''(x)\over 2}h^2-{f'''(w_1)\over 6}h^3, \\
f(x+h)&=f(x)+f'(x)h+{f''(x)\over 2}h^2+{f'''(w_2)\over 6}h^3
\end{align}
$$
Hence
$$f(x+h)-f(x-h)=2hf'(x)+{f'''(w_1)+f'''(w_2)\over 6}h^3.$$
However, I don't know how to proceed from here.
I only know that $|f(x+h)-f(x-h)|\le 2$. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$|f'(x) |\le 1$ does not necessarily hold under the given conditions, as the function $f(x) = \sin(ax)$ with $a^3 = 1$ shows.

We can show $|f'(x) |\le 3/2$:
$$ 
f'(x) = \frac{f(x+h)-f(x-h)}{2h} - \frac{f'''(w_1)+f'''(w_2)}{12} h^2
$$
so that
$$
 |f'(x)| \le \frac 1h + \frac{h^2}{2}
$$
for all $h > 0$. Setting $h=1$ gives $|f'(x) |\le 3/2$.

---

This is a special case of the [Landau–Kolmogorov inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landau%E2%80%93Kolmogorov_inequality): The sharp bound is
$$
 \Vert f' \Vert_\infty \le C(3, 1, \Bbb R) \cdot \Vert f \Vert_\infty^{2/3} \cdot \Vert f''' \Vert_\infty^{1/3}
$$
where
$$
 C(3, 1, \Bbb R) = K_2 K_3^{-2/3}
$$
and the $K_j$ are the [Favard constants](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FavardConstants.html). This gives
$$
\Vert f' \Vert_\infty \le \frac 12 3^{2/3} \cdot \Vert f \Vert_\infty^{2/3} \cdot \Vert f''' \Vert_\infty^{1/3} \\
\le \frac 12 3^{2/3} \cdot 1^{2/3} \cdot 3^{1/3} = \frac 32 \, .
$$

So the upper found $|f'(x) |\le 3/2$ that we determined is indeed best possible.

Comment: Thank you for this beautiful answer. I had no idea that the optimal constants were known in such an explicit way! I am quite surprised by the fact that the Landau-Kolmogorov Wikipedia page does not mention the Gagliardo-Nirenberg one, and conversely... Is there a difference between both theories? LK seems to concern the 1D-$L^\infty$ setting, but the Wiki page also mentions "generalizations" to $L^p$ with $p \in [1,\infty)$.

Comment: @cs89: I am afraid that I cannot help you with that. I know the Landau-Kolmogorov inequality from the Wikipedia page, and I have read Landau's article “Einige Ungleichungen Fur Zweimal Differentiierbare Funktionen” but I am not familiar with the Gagliardo-Nirenberg inequality or the relation between those theories.